# Exit command line Network.framework app that uses dispatch_main()

Tags: objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, command-line-tool, network.framework

Playing with low-level networking code in several languages on several platforms, [I followed this example from the Apple developer forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/711731) to get a [Network.framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/network) example working.

It works great but the app never exits back to the commandline due to using [`dispatch_main()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/1452860-dispatch_main).

The documentation is very sparse, examples are not common, and tutorials barely exist at all. Hunting around the internet all I find is mentions that this never returns, but I can't find anything about how to break out of it when I actually want to return.

I'm assuming this relies on background knowledge of GCD (grand central dispatch) and runloops and such that I don't have and that isn't easy to find. Perhaps it's only relevant for a commandline app but most Apple code is for GUI?

So is there a way to break out of/return from the loop/thread/etc that `dispatch_main` puts me in? Or is there some alternative API or method other than `dispatch_main` that you're supposed to use when you intend to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you probably want to use the C function `void exit(int status);` See the output of `man 3 exit`. This will run various standard C cleanup processes and cause your process to exit cleanly with the status code you call it with.

What's perhaps more interesting is the question: "How does your process know *when* to call `exit()`?" Is it going to receive a network payload that tells it when to quit? Will you send it a UNIX `SIGTERM` signal? (If this feels like a misuse of `SIGTERM` to you, you could consider using `SIGUSR1` or `SIGUSR2`.) GCD has signal handling capabilities built in (see `DispatchSource.makeSignalSource` [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchsource/2300045-makesignalsource)). To be more explicit, you could add a GCD signal handler for `SIGTERM` do whatever other cleanup you need to do, and then call `exit()` at the end of the handler block, and that should do the trick.

Hope that helps!

Comment: The code sends a network request and receives the response. So I would stop upon either getting an error from a network call or after receiving the response. BUT I'd also worry that `exit()` might be too low-level and not allow for proper cleanup of the higher level mac-specific stuff, since I'm out of my environment and don't really know which parts of the rabbithole to go down (-:

Comment: In this situation, It's up to you to do whatever cleanup you need to do. `dispatch_main()` is clearly documented as "This function never returns." so you're going to need some sort of heavier hand to exit from a process that uses that as its main loop (i.e. `exit()` or `abort()` etc.)

Comment: OK so I'm not bypassing anything internal, only code I specifically put there? Gotcha. By the way, after posting here I got an answer I couldn't verify from an AI chatbot saying I should use `dispatch_after(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ exit(0); });` In an effort to explain my confusion, when I was playing with `NSApplication` some time ago I found out I should use `NSApp.stop()` to return back to the main code after launching the GUI loop with `NSApplication.shared.run()` rather than just call `exit(0)`.

Comment: A couple of things: If you just call `exit()` without cleaning up stuff your code created (i.e. objects created using the `create_*` functions of Network.framework) then things may not be cleaned up "correctly". You created those objects, you should destroy them. If you want to use `atexit()` to schedule cleanup, that's another option. That said, when you call `exit` your process will terminate. All sockets closed, all file handles closed, all memory given back to the OS, etc. It's a big hammer. But if you created temporary files not managed by `tmpfile()`, you'd need to delete them, etc.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind: Almost every framework you might consume allocates private, global-ish data structures that you cannot explicitly release, except by virtue of your process terminating. WebKit is a great example: it allocates hundreds of MB of internal data structures that you have no way to force it to clean up, other than by terminating the process. I suggest explicitly handling the things you own/create, and trusting that the framework either handles its own cleanup, or *doesn't care* about not cleaning up.